# Getting Image Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError after updating to Paperclip 3.4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I got the following message after upgrading:

> Paperclip 3.0 introduces a non-backward compatible change in your
>   attachment path. This will help to prevent attachment name clashes
>   when you have multiple attachments with the same name. If you didn't
>   alter your attachment's path and are using Paperclip's default, you'll
>   have to add `:path` and `:url` to your `has_attached_file` definition.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> has_attached_file :avatar,
>   :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
>   :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
> ```

So I did so:

post.rb:

```
 has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "170x300>",
                                         :thumb => "142x185>" },
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
                    :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
```

But then I saw this error message:

> - Image Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

I even added this to `environments/development.rb`:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"
```

(`which identify` outputs `/usr/bin/identify`)

But still no luck.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, I didn't expect this. The problem wasn't due to upgrading.
It was because the file I was uploading was named like this:

```
Screenshot at 2012-11-26 16:22:44.png
```

Weird.

Comment: Same problem here, how did you fix it?

Comment: @Martynas not sure, but I tried simpler file names like 01.png and it worked.

Comment: What I am aware of is that a real user could upload file with a name like that, and I am not sure how to handle it. These colons are being replaced automatically by rails and I think Paperclip is still trying to find a file with "not yet escaped" name.

Comment: colon in filename is creating problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the filename.
colons are not accepted, if you remove the colon from the attachment name using gsub it'll be accepted always.